# Extract function from integrating by parts

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives, indefinite-integrals, complex-integration

It is known that:

$\int u(t) v'(t) \,dt=u(t)v(t)-\int u'(t)v(t)\,dt$

Is it possible to "bracket out" the function $v(t)$ on the right side, i.e .:

$u(t)v(t)-\int u'(t)v(t)\,dt=(???) \cdot v(t)$

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Also keep in mind the integral bounds. I think it is necessary tobe precise here

Comment: You can solve for (???), but that is not much better than just extracting $uv-\int u’v dt$ as you already have the $v(t)$ there. If you mean to find a closed form for the integral, then we need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume this was possible and consider some non-elementary integrable function $f$. Let $u(x) = x, v = f$ and denote your $(\dots)$ by $h(x)$. Furthermore let's assume that $h$ is an elementary function because otherwise it is of course trivially possible but of no real use. Then
$$
u(x)v(x) - \int u'(x) v(x) dx = x f(x) - \int f(x) dx = h(x) \cdot f(x) \implies \int f(x) dx = (x - h(x)) f(x)
$$
which would be an elementary function for the integral of $f$. But this contradicts our assumption. Thus it is in general not possible to do this.